# Why is there pain and suffering according to Norse mythology?

Tags: norse

There was obviously pain and suffering in the world, was it seen as a punishment or was it just seen as something normal and there was no reason for it?

Answer (score -1):

I don't think the Ancient Norse thought much about pain and suffering, they probably welcomed it as they believed that dying in war was the honourable way to die while dying of old age or natural causes was seen as dishonourable and cowardice. Though I'm not 100% sure it's just my best guess on the matter.